How to Encrypt the Password before sending it to backend in django
I am making user authentication django project and for frontend I am just using templates and not any frontend library like react so when user submits the sign up form i want to encrypt the password before sending it to backend how can i do it?
I tried of using fetch to encrypt the password so when the form is submitted i am encrypting the password and sending it backend using fetch
// adding on_submit event listener to the form
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    console.log(' in submit event')
    const form = document.querySelector("#forgot_password_form");
  
    form.addEventListener("submit", async function (event) {
      // preventing form from reloading when submitted
      event.preventDefault();
      // fetching user entered details ie., email,password,confirm password
      const email = document.getElementById("forgot_password_mail").value;
      
      console.log('user details', email)
      error_in_signin_data = false
      document.getElementById('email_required_msg').style.display='none'
      document.getElementById('valid_email_required_msg').style.display='none'
      
      document.getElementById("forgot_password_mail").style.borderColor = '#e3e3e3';
      
      // check if email is empty or not
      if (email.length == 0) {
        // error_fields.push("signin_email")
        // error_message_array.push("Email")
        document.getElementById('email_required_msg').style.display='block'
        document.getElementById("forgot_password_mail").style.borderColor = 'red';
        error_in_signin_data = true;
      } 
      else{
        // Check if the email is in correct format
        if (!email.match(emailRegex)) {
            // error_fields.push("signin_email")
            // error_message_array.push("Valid Email")
            document.getElementById('valid_email_required_msg').style.display='block'
            document.getElementById("forgot_password_mail").style.borderColor = 'red';
            error_in_signin_data = true;
          }
      }
      
      // fetching CSRF token from form
      const csrfToken = form.querySelector("[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").value;
  
      const formData = new FormData();
  
      formData.append("email", email);
  
      // console log formData object values to make sure they are same as user entered values
      for (const value of formData.values()) {
        console.log('formData', value);
      }
      
      if(!error_in_signin_data){
        try {
            const response = await fetch("", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": csrfToken,
              },
              body: formData,
            });
            if (response.ok) {
              let data = await response.text();
              console.log('Server Response:', data);
      
              if (data === 'forgot_password_success') {
                document.getElementById('success_msg').innerText = 'Reset Password Link Sent, Kindly Check Your Mail';
                document.getElementById('success_container').style.display='block';
              } else if (data == "Something Went Wrong, Try Again"){
                document.getElementById('error_msg').innerText = 'Something Went Wrong, Try Again';
                document.getElementById('error_container').style.display='block';
              } else if (data == "Email not Registered"){
                document.getElementById('error_msg').innerText = "Email not Registered, Try with Regsitered Mail";
                document.getElementById('error_container').style.display='block';
              } else{ 
                // Login failed, display error message
                document.getElementById('error_msg').innerText = 'Something went wrong, try again';
                document.getElementById('error_container').style.display='block';
              }
            }
          } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error:", error);
            // Handle the error
            document.getElementById('error_msg').innerText = 'Something went wrong, try again';
            document.getElementById('error_container').style.display='block';
          }
      }
      
    });
  });

but the issue is that I am unable to render the templates as view response so what happening is that when
the view response is rendering a template then instead of rendering the template the whole html code of the template is being returned as response for the fetch statement
so i want to encrypt the password in frontend and then send the enrypted data to backend while just using only templates for frontend how can i do it?
